# How do I implement a physics gun?

Tags: mathematics, physics, matrix

I'm currently trying to implement a [physics gun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=bDoarTCUxUA#t=72s) for my game. What I want is for the entity to stay in the same position on the screen no matter how I wiggle the camera about, what is the correct way to achieve this?

I threw together a basic physics gun in 5 minutes (just to handle grabbing and moving the object) but it [doesn't work as intended](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPVmPutUbu4). The problem is obviously that I only handle changes in toolDirection (rotation) but largely ignore changes in toolPosition (translation). For reference, here is my current script (wrtten in Lua):

```
local toolPosition; --This always holds the position of the tool
local toolDirection; --This always holds a normalized vector indicating the direction the tool is pointing
local grabLocation; --This is the position in world space where the ray from the tool intersected the body of the entity

function UpdateTargetPosition()
    local relativeGrabDirection = (grabLocation - toolPosition).Normalize();                 --direction from tool to target grab point

    local axis = relativeGrabDirection.Cross(toolDirection);
    local angle = math.acos(relativeGrabDirection.Dot(toolDirection));
    local rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);

    local transform = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(-toolPosition) * Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation) * Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(toolPosition);
    target.SetWorldTransform(target.GetWorldTransform() * transform);
    grabLocation = grabLocation.TransformByMatrix4x4(transform);
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all? Looks like a pretty good go for 5 minutes. So you already know what you need to do, what are you looking for from us?

Comment: I know I need to handle translation, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem is that's causing rotation when I translate in the current version. Of course if I don't know that, then I don't know how I need to change the transform matrix to fix it :(

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to *do*.